# why jquery each() not iterating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to place a scroll indication on each tab which is built with Jquery UI. As it happens the code below works for the first tab and stops there.
I tested and it goes just fine up till the if statement for all ul, but only the first ul passes through the if statement, even if the second ul at least also gives a true for that if

What am I missing?

Also I understand that each() will stop in case of false. How can I go around that?

```
var i = 0;
$(".comp_pr ul").each(function () {
    var element0 = $(this).attr('id');
    var element1 = "#" + element0;
    var element = document.querySelector(element1);
    if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
        $(element1 + ' ' + "li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)").html('scroll <img id=""       src="img/forward.png" title=""/>');
        $(element1 + ' ' + "li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)").attr('class', 'zscroll');
        $(element1 + ' ' + "li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)").attr('id', 'zs' + i);
    }
    i++;
});
```

A quick summary of the HTML:

```
<div class="comp_pr">
<ul id="measure0">
<li></li>
......
</ul>
</div>

<div class="comp_pr>
<ul id="measure1"
<li></li>
......
</ul></div> 
....
```

Comment: Please add the HTML markup so we can help you. Also, loop stops only if you return false.. which is not your case..

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` : no. `this.id` : yes.

Comment: your i variable is not needed, you can use the included index parameter like so `.each(function (i) {`

Comment: you don't need that queryselector thing, `this` is already your element. most likely one of the ul's doesn't have an id attribute, so you try queryselecting `#undefined`, and `element.offsetHeight` throws an error like `offsetHeight is not a property of undefined`; did you look into your console?

Comment: The whole element\element0\element1 is unnessasary take a look at http://pastebin.com/y2Jx46du

Comment: @Musa selecting `li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)` **3** times is also unnecessary

Comment: I didn't actually notice that http://pastebin.com/BVNee8Gn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other tabs are hidden, right?  So their Height and Width will be 0.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: It's not going into the if statement because the height and width are 0 for hidden elements.  How does that not answer the question?

Comment: @YotamOmer I would not class this as a comment.

Comment: how do you know the elements are hidden?

Comment: I know they're hidden, because that's how jQuery UI tabs work, one is displayed, the rest are hidden.

Comment: Barbara. Thanks. I think you may have nailed it. Other tabs are hidden indeed at the time the function is run( at document.ready). Any idea how to get that scroll indication in place for those hidden tags?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Congratulations. haha. it's always good to have the last laugh. **+1**

Comment: You could add it to the beforeActivate callback 

$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {}
});

Comment: Barbara Laird. Following your comments above I arrived to a solution (see answer). It needs to be on activate, though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is extremely inefficient, here is the same code, improved:

```
$("#comp_pr ul").each(function (i) {
    if ((this.offsetHeight < this.scrollHeight) || (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth)) {
        $(this).find('li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)').html('scroll <img src="img/forward.png" title=""/>').addClass('zscroll').attr('id', 'zs' + i);
    }
});
```

Also, I'm not sure we can diagnose your actual issue without HTML markup to test against.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any offset height methods, so i will quickly change that for you

Comment: Neil S, Pinocchio. Thanks for the much improved code. Still it does not solve the issue. As Barbara pointed out it probably has to do with the fact that tabs other than the first one are hidden at the moment the function is run. Any ideas on that>

Comment: @BernardA so what is the purpose of the conditional in the first place?

Comment: Neil S. I am not sure I understand your question, but the if statement checks if there is overflow or not. If yes an icon is placed to indicate that to the user, so that he may scroll right. This was gracefully supplied by link: http://jsbin.com/ujiwah/4/edit

Comment: well, in that case, you would need to call the function when the tab is made visible. I'm not completely familiar with JQUI's tab functions, but you should be able to attach the whole function to the click event on the tabs, and it would always skip the hidden tabs but check the visible tab.

Answer (score 0):

After Barbara Laird showed me the way I came up with the following, which is working for me, for anyones reference.
Note that it needs to be on tabs activate (activate), not beforeActivate, as only after activation you can get the measures.

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
activate: function(event,ui) {
var tabid = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
var i = tabid.charAt(tabid.length-1)-1;
ulid = "#measure" + i;
var element = document.querySelector(ulid);
if( (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
    $(ulid).find('li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(3)').html('scroll <img src="img/forward.png" title=""/>').addClass('zscroll').attr('id', 'zs' + i);
}
}
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

ids should be unique which could cause you problems, use a classname instead, also might be worth trying `++i;`

Comment: Why would `++i;` be better than `i++;`?

Comment: heres a little something on pre and post increment operators http://goo.gl/Y04Ncd

Comment: I understand that article's point about how the post increment is (obviously) not compiled to the same thing as the pre (and how post could be less efficient), but you're not seriously suggesting that changing from post to pre increment will affect the result  (when not used as part of a larger expression)? It's fine for you to provide general advice with your answer, but you presented this as if it would help solve the problem.

Comment: didnt say he must use it, i said `it might be worth trying` it